# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /nas/content/live/inboundpro/leadportal/index.php on line 35

Tags: php, pdo

Im getting a interesting error message. It says that my $databaseConnection is considered a non object in my script. But this script works perfectly fine on my test server. Any idea why pdo would consider my $databaseConnection a non object?

PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /nas/content/live/inboundpro/leadportal/index.php on line 35

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    //DB configuration Constants
    define('_HOST_NAME_', '162.242.221.151;3306');
    define('_USER_NAME_', '*****');
    define('_DB_PASSWORD', '*****');
    define('_DATABASE_NAME_', '*****');

    $user = '*****';
    $pass = '*****';
    //PDO Database Connection
    try {
        $databaseConnection = new PDO('mysql:host=162.242.221.151;dbname=wp_inboundpro', $user, $pass);
        $databaseConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $errMsg = '';
        //username and password sent from Form
        $username = trim($_POST['username']);
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);

        if($username == '')
            $errMsg .= 'You must enter your Username<br>';

        if($password == '')
            $errMsg .= 'You must enter your Password<br>';



            if($errMsg == ''){
                $records = $databaseConnection->prepare('SELECT id,username,password,hash FROM  tbl_users WHERE username = :username');
                $records->bindParam(':username', $username);
                $records->execute();
                $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                if(count($results) > 0 && password_verify($password, $results['hash'])){
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $results['username'];
                    $_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
                    header('location:dashboard.php');
                    exit;
                }else{
                    $errMsg .= 'Username and Password are not found<br>';
                }
            }
        }
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>Login Page PHP Script</title>
<link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="front">
        <div class="center">

            <div class="LoginPortal">
                <?php
                    if(isset($errMsg)){
                        echo '<div style="color:#FF0000;text-align:center;font-size:12px;background-color:white;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;">'.$errMsg.'</div>';
                    }
                ?>
                <form action="" method="post">
                    <div class="formTop"><img src="images/IP_Logo_SOLO.png"></div>

                    <div class="Formcenter">
                    <input type="text" name="username" class="box" placeholder="USERNAME"/>
                    <input type="password" name="password" class="box" placeholder="PASSWORD"/><br />
                    <input type="submit" name='submit' value="Submit" class='submit'/>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div><!-- close center -->
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any prob in the correct direction would be awesome. I'm a beginner at PDO

Comment: Your interpreter is not lying dear ```$databaseConnection``` is not an database object ```var_dump( $databaseConnection )``` should give you clear idea.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu: the question is why would the var become a non-object between the time `new PDO()` is executed and the prepare is called...

Comment: i guess my question is why isnt $databaseConnection a database object? I have this script running on my test server and it all works together fine. Which is the part that is confusing me

Comment: @YvesLeBorg php only has function scope, a try/catch in global scope creates global variables.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn got that , nuked the silly comment ):

Comment: @Krunkmaster You're getting this error because `$databaseConnection` is a non object, meaning it is very likely that `new PDO('mysql:host=162.242.221.151;dbname=wp_inboundpro', $user, $pass);` is failing.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn So why would this script run fine on one server (my personal 1and1 server) and not run when i move into onto my companies live server?

Comment: @Krunkmaster That's probably the exact reason why it's failing, new environments may have different configurations

Comment: Does the database exist? In your exception handler, add `die()` after the `echo Error...`

Comment: @MarcB because the connection object is not got created , so obviously parameter given are not correct .

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahur: wrong: pdo either returns a PDO object, or it throws an exception. since OP's catching the exception and displaying the error message, and NOT mentioning getting that error, something else must be going on.

Comment: I would suggest starting with looking at the webserver error logs. For apache on debian (ubuntu) systems they default to `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and redhat/centos to `/var/log/httpd/error.log`. Look to see if there are any other errors that might be causing this (such as not actually getting a connection but something else is blocking seeing that error). Add a `die` or `exit` call in your catch statement. Else the error is output and the rest of the page loads. If db connection fails, you don't want it to continue on.

Comment: I think a number of you guys are correct. I got it working. I'll post what i did to get it functioning in an hour or so if anyone is curious